# How to show the outer expansion of this solution diverge?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics

Suppose we have $\epsilon y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+y=0$. $y(1)=e^{-1/2}, y(0)$ finite,

Suppose we have shown there is no boundary layer at $x=0$ even though $\frac{1}{x}\geq 0$(caused by the regular singularity of $0$). And we consider the outer expansion $y_{out}\sim y_0(x)+\epsilon y_1(x)+......$ We need to show it is not a regular perturbation expansion, that is, we want to show it diverges.

Bender's book suggest that we can look at the exact solution to our problem, which is 
$$
y=e^{-1/2}x^{(\epsilon-1)/2\epsilon}\frac{J_{1/2-1/2\epsilon}(x/\sqrt{\epsilon})}{J_{1/2-1/2\epsilon}(1/\sqrt{\epsilon})}
$$
How do we use this? Can anyone gives some hint please?

Thanks!

Comment: The solution does not satisfy the equation, neither does it satisfy the condition at $x = 0$. The factor $e^{-1/2}$ in $y(1)$ seems to be redundant, since the problem is linear. The actual solution is
$$
c_1 x^{\frac{\epsilon -1}{2 \epsilon }} J_{\frac{\epsilon -1}{2 \epsilon
   }}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\right)+c_2 x^{\frac{\epsilon -1}{2 \epsilon }}
   Y_{\frac{\epsilon -1}{2 \epsilon }}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\right)
$$
Since none of the functions are finite at $x = 0$, both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are nonzeros